# Use redux with --template redux or install it manually

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm trying to learn redux, but there seems to be multiple ways to install or use it. Do I have to use the redux toolkit by adding it to my app when I create it with CRA or do I manually add it to my project? Which practice is better?

Answer (score 0):

Since the `--template redux` approach uses [the official Redux template](https://github.com/reduxjs/cra-template-redux), maintained by the Redux team, you can't go wrong with it. But of course it's fine so set everything up yourself, too.